# Storing a table of Data in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, store

I am new to VB.net and i am creating an application which uses a table as source for some Combo boxes. Now i have this table as data table but after i complete the application i want this table to be editable/extendable so i dont want to open Visual studio to add some more list to combo boxes. At the same time users should not able to alter the table. So what are my options?.

Is there a way , for example via data view to add and store data to data table without VS? or something like admin mode to alter the table without VS?

If i use access or sql , do other users need sql to be installed?

Thanks

Comment: Dont you have a database for your application?

Comment: You could write the datatable to XML as a stream, and encrypt that stream to write it to disk. Then write a utility to edit the datatable. I'm not suggesting that the encryption needs to be very strong, it sounds like you just want the average end-user to not be able to tamper with it using something like Notepad.

Comment: `Dim jsonResult As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject([Your DataTable])`. You could save the string Base64Encoded. Then, to load it back, `Dim dt As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(jsonContent)`, where `jsonContent` is the content of the file where you stored the JSON (decoded, of course) .

Answer (score 0):

The datatable is an Object. You can add columns and rows at runtime.
This f.e you can make in an password protected Dialog Form, but of course without saving the changes, they get lost when you close the app.

As Datasource for the Table, you could use a database, where only you have edit rights and then when the program starts, it looks the data up and shows the data in your  combo box.

ms sql server don't have  to be installed, mysql you need to download the connector dll and access needs his runtime.

Comment: thanks for all the answers ..i will check xml, JSON, and Sql options.